# Android application: wrong charset of server content

Tags: android, character-encoding, android-webview

One of our application's users says that he cannot read news comment because of wrong symbols charset. He has Galaxy Ace Duos (GT-S6802) and made a screenshot:

[image]

Nobody else complains about the error. What could be the problem?

The app loads comments (UTF-8) from server API. Text of each comment has html format (contains images) and therefore is placed in a WebView this way:

```
holder.text.loadData(text, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "utf-8");
```

App on Play Market: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kz.sportlive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. But before it I tried to encode comment text to Base64 on server and decode it on app - didn't work.

Then I tried load encoded text in WebView:

```
webview.loadData(comment.text_base64, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "base64");
```

It didn't work too.

Finally I tried this way:

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webview.loadData(comment.text, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);
```

and it works perfect!
Use it in similar situations